# Extract particular word from docx table using python native library docx

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, key-value, python-docx

The main objective of my code is to extract a particular word from the docx table.

**TextDoc.docx**

[image: Docx table]

**Extract.py**

```
from docx import *
mydoc = opendocx('/home/user/TestDoc.docx')    
search(mydoc,'Key1')
```

I got result as *True*, but my objective is something like

```
get_value('Key1')
```

output should be

```
Value1
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that directly with the legacy versions of python-docx. You'll need to be on the most recent version (~0.5.0), which has a different API.

```
pip uninstall docx
pip install python-docx
```

Something like this should work:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('..path..')
table = document.tables[0]
cell = table.row[0].cells[0]
paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
text = paragraph.text
```

Documentation for python-docx is here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Thanks solution worked with small modification.
`cell = table.rows[0].cells[0]`
`paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]`
`text1 = paragraph.text`
`print text1`